# How to add a link in Jquery PrettyPhoto to download the image

Tags: jquery, yii, prettyphoto

I am using Jquery PrettyPhoto to have a slide show, however it does not let the users to download the images. Anyone know how can I add a link to it so users will be able to download the images?

Here is my code: (I am using prettyPhoto Widget in Yii, but any answer in general for prettyPhoto will be great)

```
<?php 
  $this->beginWidget('ext.prettyPhoto.PrettyPhoto', array(
        'id'=>'pretty_photo',
        // prettyPhoto options
        'options'=>array(
            'opacity'=>0.60,
            'modal'=>true,
        ),
    ));
?>
<div class="column4-front image-gallery">

         <a href="/files/show/<?php echo $data->image; ?>" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" title="<?php echo $data->caption; ?>">
             <img src="/files/show/thumb/<?php echo $data->image; ?>" />
         </a>

</div>
<?php $this->endWidget('widgets.prettyPhoto');?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy!

HTML **(title is empty!)**

```
<a id="photo_link" href="http://link_to_image_or_video" rel="prettyPhoto" title="">
    <img src="images/play-video.png" alt="" title="" width="380" height="147" />
</a>
```

JS (inside the document ready)

```
//do not show title on download link hover (download button)
$("#photo_link").hover(function(e){

    $(this).attr('data-title', $(this).attr('title'));
    $(this).removeAttr('title');

},
function(e){

    $(this).attr('title', $(this).attr('data-title'));

}); 

//add download link on the fly on click of photo link
$("#photo_link").on('click', function(){
    $(this).attr('title', '<div class="center"><a href="#download_link" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><strong>Download</strong></a></div>');
});
```

No PrettyPhoto JS changes are necessary. Here is the simple idea. Yours to play inside Yii 
framework.

Even easier: Only JS (include JS in your view)

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    social_tools: '<div class="center"><a id="get_started" href="#contact" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><strong>Download</strong></a></div>',
    default_width: 800,
    default_height: 450
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution **don't need change PrettyPhoto JS**.

I use callback function for search the element that contain the big image and add a new element linked to image (only works in **HTML5**):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="prettyPhoto main stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>     
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <a href="images/fullscreen/2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"><img src="images/thumbnails/t_2.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Nice building" /></a>
            <a href="images/fullscreen/3.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"><img src="images/thumbnails/t_3.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Fire!" /></a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //Add callback function to prettyPhoto, called everytime an item is shown/changed
                $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
                    changepicturecallback: function(){add_download()}
                });
            });

            function add_download(){
                //If "download" class doesn't exist
                if (!$(".download")[0]){
                    //Search for the div that contains the image and add an element with Text (or image)
                    $("#pp_full_res").append('<p class="download" style="cursor: pointer;position: absolute;right: 65px;z-index: 9999;">DOWNLOAD</p>');

                    $('.download').each(function(){
                        //Add "download" attribute that only works with HTML5
                        $(this).wrap('<a target="_blank" href="' + $(this).prev().attr('src') + '" download />');
                    });
                }

            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

There is another (**no HTML5**) solution, changing:

```
$(this).wrap('<a target="_blank" href="' + $(this).prev().attr('src') + '" download />');
```

by

```
$(this).wrap('<a href="download.php?file=' + $(this).prev().attr('src') + '" />');
```

You need a "download.php" to force download img, for example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7238099/2369084

Comment: But image open in new tab. and does not work as downloading or save as option does not appeare. can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution (not for Yii) - http://loco.ru/materials/343-wordpress-nextgen-gallery-dobavit-ssylku-sohranit-foto
add link to open original image.

Answer (score 1):

well this is a lot late i guess but it'll help someone,

first of all start using the latest version and have jquery 1.4+ atleast cause not 2.0 is ready and we all better start moving lol.

ok i'll take the above example

```
 <a href='./uploads/1f.jpg' rel='prettyPhoto[gallery1]' title='Nature Photo One' >
       <img src='./uploads/1t.jpg' border='0' alt='' link='<a href="download.php?f=1f.jpg" class="url">Download This Photo</a>' />
     </a>
```

**dont** do the link="ur link" but instead use the data attribute like so

thats step 1 to change ur format a bit.

now openup ur prettyphoto.js

find

```
social_tools: '<div class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></div><div class="facebook"><iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=en_US&href={location_href}&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:500px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></div>' /* html or false to disable */
```

it'll be with all the markup in the starting.

now edit it to as below

```
social_tools: '<div class="{my_class}"><a href="{my_url}">{my_link}</a></div><br/><div class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></div><div class="facebook"><iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=en_US&href={location_href}&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:500px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></div>' /* html or false to disable */
```

next find this section

```
// Rebuild Facebook Like Button with updated href
            if(settings.social_tools){
                facebook_like_link = settings.social_tools.replace('{location_href}', encodeURIComponent(location.href)); 
                $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_social').html(facebook_like_link);
            }
```

around line 204

replace with

```
if(settings.social_tools){
                facebook_like_link = settings.social_tools.replace('{location_href}', encodeURIComponent(location.href)); 
                $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_social').html(facebook_like_link);
 settings.social_tools.replace('{my_url}',encodeURIComponent($("img[src='"+pp_images[set_position]+"']").data('link')));

// CUSTOMIZE BELOW TO YOUR NEED

settings.social_tools.replace('{my_class}','your_class');
settings.social_tools.replace('{my_link}','Go To Page');
                }
```

as said above in 2 lines u can replace '.your_class' with whatever name u want and so goes to 'Go To Page'

and all done Refresh ur page ie F5 cause this is changed in file.....and loaded and it'll work good.

cheers all.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved my problem, [here](http://www.catpin.com/prettyphoto.php) is an example that I found. They have added the link to download the photo like this:

```
<ul class='gallery clearfix'>
  <li>
     <a href='./uploads/1f.jpg' rel='prettyPhoto[gallery1]' title='Nature Photo One' >
       <img src='./uploads/1t.jpg' border='0' alt='' link='<a href="download.php?f=1f.jpg" class="url">Download This Photo</a>' />
     </a>
  </li>
  // REST OF THE IMAGES

</ul>

 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({theme: 'light_rounded'});
    });
 </script>
```

There is a need to make some changes to the jquery.prettyphoto.js file. I used v 3.1.2 which can be downloaded [here](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/)

This is the changes I made using the example that I mentioned [before](http://www.catpin.com/prettyphoto.php)

```
(function($) {
$.prettyPhoto = {version: '3.1.4'};
    $.fn.prettyPhoto = function(pp_settings) {
    pp_settings = jQuery.extend({
              //....
              social_tools: '<div class="pp_social"><span class="pp_link"></span></div>'
              // I deleted the rest in social_tools since I wasn't going to use them, you can just add this to the begining of it.
           }, pp_settings);
    //....

    /*
* Initialize prettyPhoto.
*/
$.prettyPhoto.initialize = function() {
       //...
       pp_links=(isSet)?jQuery.map(matchedObjects,function(n,i){if($(n).attr('rel').indexOf(theRel)!=-1)return($(n).find('img').attr('link'))?$(n).find('img').attr('link'):"";}):$.makeArray($(this).find('img').attr('link'));
  //...
    }

    //...
    $.prettyPhoto.open = function(event) {
       //....
       if(pp_links[set_position]!=""){$pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_link').show().html(unescape(pp_links[set_position]));}else{$pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_link').hide();}
       //....
    }
```

And if you want to use it with the [prettyphoto extention](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/prettyphoto/) in yii. You can replace the javaScript file with the file that you modified. Then:

```
<?php 
    $this->beginWidget('ext.prettyPhoto.PrettyPhoto', array(
        'id'=>'pretty_photo',
        // prettyPhoto options
        'options'=>array(
            'opacity'=>0.60,
            'modal'=>true,
            'theme'=> 'light_rounded'
        ),
    ));
?>
<div class="column4-front image-gallery">

        <a href="/files/immagini/<?php echo $data->image; ?>" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" title="<?php echo $data->caption; ?>">
             <img src="/files/immagini/thumb/<?php echo $data->image; ?>" link='<a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('compania/downloadimage',array('f'=>$data->image)); ?>" class="url">Scarica questo foto</a>'/>

         </a>

   </div>
   <?php $this->endWidget('widgets.prettyPhoto');?>
```

And add this to the related controller, for me CompaniaController:

```
 public function actionDownloadImage()
    {
        $filename = $_GET['f']; 
        $fileDir='path to image';
        Yii::app()->request->sendFile(
            $filename,
            file_get_contents($fileDir.$filename)
        );      
    }
```

Comment: No PrettyPhoto JS changes are necessary. See my solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this editing the prettyPhoto.js file in the img_markup attribute.

Change this

```
image_markup: '<img id="fullResImage" src="{path}" />',
```

To this

```
image_markup: '<img id="fullResImage" src="{path}" /><a class="pp_download" href="{path} download"><i class="enotype-icon-download"></i></a>',
```