# Modernizr a-download for download attribute does not work in IE, Safari and and Opera?

Tags: jquery, download, modernizr

I downloaded this Modernizr snippet http://modernizr.com/download/#-a_download (found under Non-core detects) and added it in the `<head>`.

My html markup looks like this:

```
<a href="test.jpg" download="test.jpg">Download file</a>
```

In Firefox and Chrome, `download` attribute is supported even without using Modernizr.

Modernizr's `a-download` is not supported by IE, Safari and Opera? Has anyone tried this before and got this working some other way?

Comment: You know that Modernizr doesn't backfill features, it just detects if the browser already supports it? Sounds like you're after a polyfill – there's a rather extensive list here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills – although I'm afraid I don't know of one for `a[download]` (might not even be possible to polyfill?)