# Download image on button click

Tags: php, html

how can i achieve the following with a button tag:

```
<a id="download" href="a.jpg" download="a.jpg">Download</a>
```

P.S: when you click on the button, it should download the a.jpg file and NOT open it in the browser.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click?lq=1

Comment: you have to point it to some php page something like download.php?file=a.jpg and in this php page set needed headers to force a download (so then the php processes the output to browser), more on google.

Comment: ok ill try that and get back.

Comment: Following the link that Briggs gave, there is an answer on that page that is worth looking into using `mod_rewrite` http://stackoverflow.com/a/2408183/1415724

Answer (score 3):

You want `Content-Disposition: attachment;` in the backend. You'll need a script handing out the images to force a download.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the attribute [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes), which is new to HTML5 and [is supported by](http://caniuse.com/download) Firefox and Chrome but not yet IE or Opera:

```
<a id="download" href="a.jpg" download="a.jpg">Download</a>
```

Comment: I want to use the button tag. So i was looking for something like the download attribute in the button tag.

Comment: Ohhhh... I had a similar issue a long time ago (before the download attribute was a potential option) so I can imagine your situation. Unfortunately, the `button` element is not an actual link, so it wouldn't make sense for it to have link-type attributes. You would need to leverage the File API a bit deeper to have the button both point to something *and* initiate a download. Will think on it, but how are you currently handling the redirect with the button?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for modern browsers

With image link

```
<a href="a.jpg" download="imageName"><img src="images/a.jpg" alt="Image"/></a>
```

With text link

```
<a href="a.jpg" download="imageName">Download Image</a>
```

[Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/download)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a   href="test.png"  download  ><input type="button" id="btn1"     onclick="saveAsImg(document.getElementById('chart_div'));" title="Download Png"  /></a>

find parent of id="btn1"  
like  $("#btn1").parent().get(0).href=$("img1").src;
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases does not work

```
<a id="download" href="a.jpg" download="a.jpg">Download</a>
```

because, server don't want to anyone download content normally method.
so we needed force download method.

I think you should
[Try this](https://github.com/Dushyantsingh-ds/php_button_download_file/blob/master/README.md)