# inserting save as download button to wordpress post for images

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok actually i am building a wordpress base site in which people came to download the wallpapers, its working all over but when i insert the image ahref tag its actually open the image not provide the download button,

I use

```
<a href="image url">button</a>
```

but with this the image opened in browser not provide the download box.

Is there any way to download the image, or any plugin to do that .....

Also checked this one but not works .....
[href image link download on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try this one:

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/" download="ImageName" title="ImageName">
    <img src="image url" alt="ImageName">
</a>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using the plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/download-shortcode/

or

Try this code snippet

```
if ( $attachments = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type'=>'image',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
) ) );
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);"
        onclick="document.execCommand(\'SaveAs\', true, \'' . get_permalink( $attachment->ID ) . '\');">
        Download This Wallpaper</a>';
}
```

Or by using the caption tags

```
[caption id="" align="alignnone" width="500" caption="Download Here"]<a href="/wp-content/uploads/whateverimage.jpg"><img alt="alt_text_here" src="/wp-content/uploads/whateverimage.jpg" title="My Title of Image" width="500" height="331" /></a>[/caption]
```

`not tested`..

Comment: where do i use this code snippet, in the post or in wordpress header file ..... ?

Comment: Try in ur any template .. or `functions.php`