# Implementing a download and view button using html that works on all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I have implemented a `Download` button using the following `HTML` code:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="url" download>Download</a>
```

When the button is clicked, the file has to be downloaded into the specified location. This seem to be working fine on `Chrome` but not on any other browser, 
where the file gets opened in a new tab. I have been stuck with this issue for some time now, and couldn't find a proper solution online. My files can be of any type and the code should work fine for all file types.

I also tried using the `content-disposition:attachment header`, the problem is that I also have a `View` button along with the download button, for opening the file to view in a new tab

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="url" target="_blank">View File</a>
```

and this wont work if I use the `content-disposition:attachment header`.

Is there any way I can use both the view and Download button together on a page and that work fine across all browsers. I am also fine if this has a solution that use javascript, but need to solve this issue somehow.

Comment: your href point on the string "url" in your code ? or you changed your code with "url" as exemple for your file url ? i think you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click

Comment: @Froggiz "url" can be any file url. It is loaded dynamically.