# Can i open a CSV file on click of a link in html using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv

If i know the absolute path of a CSV file then how can i open the CSV file using AngularJS.Is there any way that i can open it using Excel?
  Currently i am trying this

```
<a target="_self" ng-href="{{csv_link}}">download csv</a>
```

But the csv file is not opening.

Comment: what do you mean by "open the CSV file using AngularJS"? do you want to read it? because it seems you're trying to download it

Comment: Ya...i want to download it

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to download the CSV file than look at the [download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) attribue of an `<a></a>` tag.

There's a good example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click).

And here's mine:

```
<a target="_self" ng-href="{{csv_link}}" download="optional-custom-name.extension">download csv</a>
```

EDIT:

As it says in the comments (and in the linked answer), this feature is not fully supported.

Comment: note that `download` does not have full browser support

Comment: It is downloading. But a blank CSV file is coming.

Comment: @ShafilC well that's out of my hands. I don't know what's going on in that CSV

Comment: Help somebodyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

Comment: If it's downloading then I answered your question and you should accept my answer. The content of the file is not handled by the client side so you need to check your server and possibly ask another, related, question

Comment: I got the solution. When i put the CSV file in the ROOT folder of TOMCAT then the file is downloading