# Hosting video on Amazon S3 with flexibility to stream or download

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, amazon-s3

I am working on an application where some videos are uploaded to Amazon S3.
Now a user can choose to download the video or stream it.
The public url on amazon s3 is say "amazons3.com/test/file.mp4".
As of now, everytime I visit the url, it streams the video.
How to I append parameters to the url so that the video can be streamed or dowloaded.

Basically, original url should stream the video, and modified_url should download it.

Thank you!

Comment: You will need to store the file with a content disposition header. That will force the browser to treat the file as a download. For streaming, you may want to look at a streaming distribution with cloudfront.

Comment: But in that case the file will always be downloaded. It will not stream, right?

Comment: Correct, if accessed directly, if loaded into a video player it should not force a download and will do http streaming. If you want real streaming, you need to look at cloudfront streaming distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very easy way.
In the html file, instead of

```
<a href="some.s3.url" class="download">Download</a>
```

I used

```
<a href="some.s3.url" download="some.s3.url" class="download">Download</a>
```

Reference: [href image link download on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click)