# How will i select all kind of attachments likepdf,gif,jpg, in the form of link and on the click of link the files should be downloaded

Tags: php, image, download

I am able to select and display the images, but i need it to display as link and then download it on the click of link

```
$imagesDirectory =basename("images/"); //path to directory

if (is_dir($imagesDirectory))
{
    $opendirectory = opendir($imagesDirectory); // to read images from path

    while (($image = readdir($opendirectory)) !== false)
    {
        if(($image == '.') || ($image == '..'))
        {
         continue;
        }

        $imgFileType = pathinfo($image,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if(($imgFileType == 'jpg') || ($imgFileType == 'png')) //Types of files
        {
            echo "<img src='images/".$image."' width='200'> ";
        }
    }

    closedir($opendirectory);
 }
?>
```

Comment: Add `echo "<a href='images/".$image."'>Download</a>` for each image? If you want to force download the image, then change the URL to something like `download.php?img=$image` instead and read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php about how to force download.

Comment: Visit this url.
you can find your answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click

Answer (score 0):

You're very close to the answer, just wrap the image in anchor tag and pass "download" attribute to it. that's it:

```
$imagesDirectory =basename("images/"); //path to directory

if (is_dir($imagesDirectory))
{
    $opendirectory = opendir($imagesDirectory); // to read images from path

    while (($image = readdir($opendirectory)) !== false)
    {
        if(($image == '.') || ($image == '..'))
        {
         continue;
        }

        $imgFileType = pathinfo($image,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if(($imgFileType == 'jpg') || ($imgFileType == 'png')) //Types of files
        {
            /*xxxxxxxxxxxx-----Here's the Change-----xxxxxxxxxxxx*/
            echo "<a href='images/".$image."' download><img src='images/".$image."' width='200'> </a>";
        }
    }

    closedir($opendirectory);
 }
?>
```

Comment: _Note:_ IE and Safari on iOS doesn't support the `download`-attribute. https://caniuse.com/#feat=download