# I can not make auto download for this link in html

Tags: html

please help me for make auto download for this link in html:
http://s9.picofile.com/file/8316425618/Mobile_14hadis_0043.jpg

i use (download="") but when click on link open the pictures in the web page.
thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [href image link download on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click)

Answer (score 1):

did you try something like:

```
<a href="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8316425618/Mobile_14hadis_0043.jpg" download></a>
```

you can try to zip it or if your application have a backend you can solve this with a route response option, or maybe add a hint "right click save link as to download the image"

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://s9.picofile.com/file/8316425618/Mobile_14hadis_0043.jpg" download>Click here to download</a>
```