# Auto Download A File From Google Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, blueprism

I am trying to auto download the following file.  https://www.sspcrs.ie/libr/html/AllGPs_GMSContract.pdf

My code works for this http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip

This is an external file and I don't want to have to click the download button every time I need it.

Code (file_link is a variable set to https://www.sspcrs.ie/libr/html/AllGPs_GMSContract.pdf) :

```
string FILEURI = file_link;

System.Diagnostics.Process prozess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
prozess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
prozess.StartInfo.Arguments = "--download " + FILEURI;
prozess.Start();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51570836/i-can-not-make-auto-download-for-this-link-in-html

Comment: This isn't my webpage?

Comment: So... you're writing this in C#? Please [edit] your question with the appropriate language tag. Also, if you're using it, .NET version.

Comment: To be honest I'm running it via Blueprism so that's why I never had the tag in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is [blueprism](/questions/tagged/blueprism), why not just use the `Utility - File Management` VBO's action `Download File` and grab the file from that URL to a local path that way?

[image]

Comment: Well that's fantastic, thanks never knew about that one!