# Image download in a href using download attribute but not working image url on other server

Tags: php, html

i want to download image on click in a href tag

i'm using download attribute in tags but not working on other server image.

example -

is working

```
<a href="myfolder/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" target="_blank" download>Download</a>
```

but

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" target="_blank" download>Download</a>
```

is not working....

Comment: visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "not working"? What happens instead?

Comment: @IRG that is a different problem. `download` attribute does not download the file when the origin of file and the website are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to make 2 new files.

**1 file is : link.php**
Write code inside this file

```
<?php
echo '<a href="DownloadImage.php">Download</a>';
?>
```

**And 2 file is: DownloadImage.php**

Write code inside this (DownloadImage.php) file

```
<?php
$filePath = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"; 

header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($filePath)); 

readfile ($filePath);
exit(); 
?>
```

Here , **inside $filePath variable** set the path of the file you want to download.

I hope you will be able to download the file.

Comment: This code be very useful for download directly all files.......  Thanks @sanjay sisodiya

Comment: @Lalit Sharma, Please implement updated code? There was a small mistake in the file (link.php).

Answer (score 0):

***Based on sanjay sisodiya's answer***

**1.** index.html:

*Our link refers to the PHP file*

```
<a href="download.php">Download</a>
```

**2.** download.php:

*Now we can set the headers to download the file*

```
<?php
    $filePath = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"; 

    header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($filePath)); 

    readfile ($filePath);
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain further why you've copied the answer of sanjay sisodiya?

Comment: Because I've found a mistake in it and I can't comment below the answer.

Comment: And can you **explain** that mistake such that others, including the person you are copying from, can learn from it?

Comment: @sanjay sisodiya missed an 'echo' from the link.php, so it resulted an error, but sorry, if I want to help you, you've definitely realized the problem without my answer. And yes, I mentioned his username. **Edit: That's true that I didn't explain the problem directly in the answer.**

Answer (score 0):

The download works with the same origin only. If you refer an image outside (google.com) your domain it prevents the download.