# Download button code is not working .why?

Tags: html, css

My download code is not working .I know its a simple code but i'm stuck .I tried many things .but those code working perfectly ok over there but not in my web ..

Plese don't don't show an articals  .I know kown to do this  but it is not working now .

I'll be very great full if you edit my code ...

Please help

```html
<html>
<body>

  <a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>Achievements</a>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you I edit it but it still not working @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

> [href image link download on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click)

And try this:

```
<html>
<body>

  <a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download="myw3schoolsimage.jpg">Achievements</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is opening perfectly not do not opening @rxdue

Comment: check the url, maybe try to display it with <img src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg">

Comment: it does but do not download it

Comment: Where are you testing your code? I've tried this with Chrome and Xampp it works fine...

Comment: You need to open the file from localhost using xampp or iis on windows... you can't download if you open the html file with Chrome, the file has to be load from webserver

Comment: can you explain how can i do this ?

Comment: [link](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) Download and install XAMPP, then run your code with it. @shahmir
Once installed start Apache, click to explorer and open htdocs. This is the root of your local webserver, you can place your HTML file here and open in Chrome with: localhost/yourHTMLfile.html
Even better you can create a folder inside htdocs like 'shahmir' and rename your HTML file in index then move it into 'shahmir'.
From Chrome you can open it with: localhost/shahmir

Comment: thanks what if I put this code and hope that It will work when i host it

Comment: <html>
<body>

  <a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download="myw3schoolsimage.jpg">Achievements</a>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

Is it maybe a typo in `download`?

```html
<html>
<body>

  <a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>Achievements</a>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for helping but it still not working.it  open properly but did not download

Comment: What browser are you using to test it? Some older browsers don't support the download attribute.

Comment: Is the image in the same origin? Download supports only same origin.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p>Click on the image to download it:<p>
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
  <img src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>

<p><b>Note:</b> The download attribute is not supported in IE or Edge (prior version 18), or in Safari (prior version 10.1).</p>
```

Comment: it  open properly but did not download

Comment: What about that one 
<a href="/path/to/image" download="myimage"><img src="/path/to/image" /></a>

Comment: still not downloading