# Is there any way to make this download button to work using https link?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to download something from another website, I have tried this but didn't work. Please I need a help here

```
<a href="https://www.samanthaming.com/logo.png" class="text-1 text-uppercase" download> download here</a>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to download, that URL is throwing a 404?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [href image link download on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click)

Comment: just an Image file

Comment: What image file, as said, that URL doesn't exist? Do you own that site?

Comment: No but I want kind of a thing if i click the link it will download the file not to be opening the link page

Comment: Yes that's right !

Comment: If "_Save Link As..._" in your browser is too cumbersome you'd have to write a script that fetches the URL and send it out along with headers so it is downloaded. The `download` attribute works for same-origin links

Comment: But can you help me with the script that does it

Answer (score 0):

At first, make sure the download link is valid. Now You can make a custom javascript function to force download from an external link.

```
<script>
    function downloadForce(link){
        var url = link.getAttribute("data-href");
        var fileName = link.getAttribute("download");
        link.innerText = "Downloading...";
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        xhr.onload = function(){
            var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(this.response);
            var tag = document.createElement('a');
            tag.href = imageUrl;
            tag.download = fileName;
            document.body.appendChild(tag);
            tag.click();
            document.body.removeChild(tag);
            link.innerText="download here";
        }
        xhr.send();
    }
    </script>
     
    <a class="text-1 text-uppercase" href="#" data-href='https://i.imgur.com/U2KQsBD.jpeg' download="image.jpeg" onclick='downloadForce(this)'>download here</a>
```

Comment: please does this script work for you because it didn't work for me

Comment: it downloaded empty image that's zero byte

Comment: This code is working for me and I have checked in several browsers. Could you please check this link? 
https://ruhulmus.w3spaces.com/forcedownload.html