# Download QR code generated using Javscript

Tags: javascript, qr-code

I'm using this library which generates QR codes as PNG images: https://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/

I want to have a download button for the generated QR code, however the canvas only appear when the image is generated. Any tips on how to put a download button?

Here's my sample code for my project:

PHP:

```
<div>
    <!-- <input type="text" id="qr-data" value="<?php echo uniqid();; ?>"/> -->
    <button onclick="generateQR()">Generate</button>
    <div id="qrcode"></div>
    <script src="qrcode.min.js"></script>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    var qrdata = document.getElementById("qr-data");
    var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"));

    function generateQR() {
        var data = qrdata.value;
        qrcode.makeCode(data);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What QR lib are you using? Edit your question and add a link to it.  What does it generate - an image? SVG?

Comment: I use Javascript lib for the QR code, it generates QR code in PNG format..

Comment: How is this question related to PHP? Also, keep in mind that the library you are using hasn't seen any activity since more than six years - maybe you should switch to any other?

Comment: I've updated my answer to work with your code.

Comment: with `var qrdata = document.getElementById("qr-data");` it appears that you commented that out in the HTML?  Please edit your question with at least the basic working example

Comment: @Don'tPanic oooohhhh... great help! thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

A quick search turns up [a simple way to download an image when clicking on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click):

- we need a link;
- with a `download` attribute;
- with the same `href` as the image `src`;

The image `src` we're after doesn't exist until the code is generated.  So we need to dynamically copy it once it is created.  So we'll need to add a download link/button to your HTML, and to copy the QR code `src` to the link `href` after it is generated.

So first up, add the link:

```
<a id="download" href="" download="qr.png"><button>Download</button></a>
```

Next, we need to copy the generated `src`.  One catch is that we need to wait for the QR code to be generated before we can copy it.  Trying to do the copy immediately after your `makeCode()` line does not work, because `makeCode()` takes some time to run, and runs asynchronously.  That means code immediately after that line will run before `makeCode()` has finished - we can't copy the `src` before the `src` exists!

There are no documented success- or done-type events or callbacks for QRCode.js, so the safest option seems to be to do it later, when the download button is clicked.  So add an event listener for our download link:

```
var link = document.getElementById("download");
link.addEventListener("click", setUpDownload);
```

And add the `setUpDownload()` function which actually does the copy:

```
function setUpDownload() {
    // Find the image inside the #qrcode div
    var image = document.getElementById("qrcode").getElementsByTagName("img");

    // Get the src attribute of the image, which is the data-encoded QR code
    var qr = image[0].src;

    // Copy that to the download link
    link.href = qr;
}
```

And we're done!  [Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/76vtrs58/).

**Side Note**

It is considered best practice to separate your HTML from your JS.  That means using event handlers in JS, rather than using inline `onclick()`.  I'd suggest changing this:

```
<button onclick="generateQR()">Generate</button>
```

To this (give it an `id` to make it easy to reference later):

```
<button id="button">Generate</button>
```

And adding an event listener in your JS to do the same job:

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", generateQR);
```