# upload external image and save it on my server

Tags: php

I want be able to upload an image or just paste the URL of an image in order to upload it a sa profile picture for my website users.

the point is i dont wanna store the url but i want to have a copy of that image on my server because if that external image will be lost i dont want to lose it either...

i believe facebook and tumblr etc do so... what the php script or best practice to do that?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the contents (bytes) from the image using the PHP function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png');
```

You can use CURL library as well... Here's an example of how you can downloadImageFromUrl with and save it in a local SaveLocation

```
function downloadImageFromUrl($imageLinkURL, $saveLocationPath) {
   $channel = curl_init();
   $curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_URL, $imageLinkURL);
   $curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
   $curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $fileBytes = curl_exec($channel); 
   curl_close($channel);

   $fileWritter = fopen($saveLocationPath, 'w');
   fwrite($fileWritter, $fileBytes);
   fclose($fileWritter); 
}
```

You can use this as follows:

```
downloadImageFromUrl("http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png", "/tmp/ps_logo2.png")
```

You can also get the same name of the image by parsing the URL as well...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is you are looking for: [Copy Image from Remote Server Over HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909374/copy-image-from-remote-server-over-http)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function called `imagecreatefromjpeg` or something. It takes a URL path to the image and creates a new image off of that. Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php

There's different functions for different extensions, though (if you prefer using such). You may need to check for the image extension from the URL and use the appropriate function I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Handling uploads is covered [in this documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), and if users paste a URL, I'd recommend using [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to save a copy of the image to your server, and then you can simply store the path to that image, rather than the external image.