# save an image from a URL then save it into a directory php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [save image from php url using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/save-image-from-php-url-using-php)

How can i use php to save/grab an image from another domain(not on  my domain/server) and save it in a directory of my site.

The URL of the image for example , will be :

```
http://anothersite/images/goods.jpg
```

How can i use PHP to grab "good.jpg" ,and save it in my directory which is `www.mysite.com/directory/`

I hope someone could guide me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should be able to use `file_get_contents` for this one. In order to use an URL with `file_get_contents` make sure `allow_url_fopen` is enabled in you `php.ini` file.

```
define('DIRECTORY', '/home/user/uploads');

$content = file_get_contents('http://anothersite/images/goods.jpg');
file_put_contents(DIRECTORY . '/image.jpg', $content);
```

Make sure that you have write permission to the directory where you want to store the image; to make the folder writable you could do this:

```
chmod +w /home/users/uploads
```

**References**

1. [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
2. [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)
3. [chmod command](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html)

Comment: thanks Krister , but how can i put it in specific directory?

Answer (score 4):

This link may be answer your question:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909374/copy-image-from-remote-server-over-http
```

to me the following code should serve ur need:

```
$url = "http://other-site/image.png";
$dir = "/my/local/dir/";
$lfile = fopen($dir . basename($url), "w");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $lfile);

fclose($lfile);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: You can specify an relative or absolute path to the output file as long as you have write permission to that specific directory.