# Php - How to save a wordpress.com dynamically generated image to the server

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress.com

Wordpress.com offers a service that allows to generate a website snapshot on the fly using url formed like this example:

https://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/http%3A%2F%2Fnytimes.com?w=612

I tried with `copy`

```
copy('https://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/http%3A%2F%2Fnytimes.com?w=612',/local/path/file.jpg);
```

But it doesn't work. Also, if I put a static image as `copy` first parameter the command works.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You want to save an image from an URL to your server?

[save an image from a URL then save it into a directory php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382098/save-an-image-from-a-url-then-save-it-into-a-directory-php)