# Uploading image with url address in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

CodeIgniter upload library only supports uploading image file from PC.

I am trying to make a code that a user can upload image with image url address.

http://example.com/photo/jake2910.jpg

I simply send this image address to server and upload the photo.

Is there a way to do that? (trust me I tried different codes already for few days.)

Comment: Best thing you can try here is php's file_get_contents() and file_put_contents(). Load your image into memory and write it on server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need in CI's upload library at all. You can simply download the file with this code:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/photo/jake2910.jpg';
/* Extract the filename */
$filename = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
/* Save file wherever you want */
file_put_contents('upload/'.$filename, file_get_contents($url));
```

But be very cautious about what files you are trying to save. Remember that even images can be stuffed with vulnerable code.

Comment: It copies image address and file name but failed to copy image data. it shows me that copied image is 0 byte.

Comment: Tested the code once again. It works. I can suggest that there are some restrictions on the webserver preventing hotlinking or something. Can you please provide the url you're trying to save?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
copy('http://example.com/photo/jake2910.jpg', '/mylocation/jake2910.jpg');
```

for more details you can check this similar post

[Copy Image from Remote Server Over HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909374/copy-image-from-remote-server-over-http)

Comment: The directive `allow_url_fopen` needs to be on though, and in many servers I've seen it isn't

Comment: @pinaldesai failed to copy the image...  it shows me that copied image is 0 byte