# How to upload file without form some url to my directory in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-3

I set login with google on my website and google get me some url like [image] So I do not have a form then how do I upload this url image to my directory?

I have no resources from any site for this issue.

Comment: just save this in column no need to save in directory

Comment: but i have to save because we need specific data of all users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using CI libaray.Lets try...

```
$url = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-MzgndtILI5I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAs/qB7MkGWroIY/photo.jpg';
/* Extract the filename */
$filename = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
/* Save file wherever you want */
file_put_contents('upload/'.$filename, file_get_contents($url));
```

Also take reference from here...
[Saving image from PHP URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url) and [Uploading image with url address in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795106/uploading-image-with-url-address-in-codeigniter)