# Rewrite image path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I rewrite the image path on my website?

i.e. on `imagesite.com/images` I host my images and on `website.com` I have my website.

On `website.com` I use the images hosted on `imagesite.com/images`.
Of course the URL on `website.com` is pointing to `imagesite.com/images`,
is there some way that I can make it look like the images are hosted on
`website.com`?

Answer (score 6):

By default, no, mod_rewrite's internal redirects don't work across domains, unless both domains are hosted on the same server.

You could of course *redirect* requests to the other server:

```
 RewriteRule ^images/(.*) http://imagesite.com/images/$1 [R]
```

but this may not be what you want (the browser's address bar will show the address of the image server).

You can, however, use the [P flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) to have mod_proxy make a proxy request. The example given in the manual is exactly what you'd like to achieve:

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.(jpg|gif|png)$ http://images.example.com/$1.$2 [P]
```

mod_proxy is very cool, but it's probably more economical and easier to just handle this with a server-side language: internally redirect requests to a script which fetches the remote image and outputs it - [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/909374/477453) for solutions for this.