# Getting a image with file_get_html, is it possible to copy a image and upload it to your own server?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

i am currently working on a project where i need to get a exsternal pages content with php, i am using

```
file_get_html()
```

to pass the html, now, is it possible to get images? and then upload them with

```
move_uploaded_file()
```

If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great

Comment: To clearify, i do not want to link to the image, i want to get the image and upload it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy Image from Remote Server Over HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909374/copy-image-from-remote-server-over-http)

Comment: looks like you are using `simplehtmldom` library. Create array of images from img tags, then use curl to retrieve them. Not hard to search SO and web on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using curl if you want to return images to your server. I've done this a few times and it is much easier (in my opinion) to grab the images you want. Something like the following might work for you if you already have the path to the external image: http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/php/php-save-images-using-curl/

This can also open up a lot more flexibility on grabbing external pages quickly.