# PHP - Upload image from external server

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to post a photo to Facebook and it works as long as the image is in the same folder as the PHP script:

```
  $file= "myimage.png";
    $args = array(
        'message' => 'Photo from application',
        );
      $args[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath($file);
    $ch = curl_init();
```

What do I need to change to make it work for *external images*, e.g.:

```
$file= "http://www.example.com/myimage.png";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url-using-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909374/copy-image-from-remote-server-over-http

Comment: There I found two answers for you with a single well thought Google search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must first download the image to your server then use that path.  Here's an example of downloading the image to a temporary file:

```
$temp_name = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "external");
copy($file, $temp_name);
// ...
$args[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath($temp_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

To be sure file is downloaded without damage I prefer this way.

```
$path = '/where/to/save/file';
$url = 'http://path.to/file';

$remote = fopen($url, "rb");
if($remote) {
    $local = fopen($path, "wb");
    if($local) {
        while(!feof($remote)) {
            fwrite($local, fread($remote, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8);
        }
    }
}
if ($remote) fclose($remote);
if ($local)  fclose($local);
```

I recommend using `uniqid()` to generate the path.

Then pass the path to your code.

Since the file will now be local it should upload just fine.

Comment: Hi can you please explain more I'm trying to upload image using your code but I didn't succeed. Thank you

Comment: The code downloads it does not upload. The ticket title is confusing. Uploading files is more complicated since you probably also need to authenticate.