# Manage images on a remote server without using FTP

Tags: php, ftp, file-transfer

I have a webapp and I want to be able to view all images from a website  on it.

**I own the website and have access to it's server** so as far as access goes I'm all good. I want to be able to view all the images and if I want, I would like to be able to replace the image on the website from the webapp. This is to allow clients of mine to be able to modify the images via the webapp on the website I'm creating / hosting for them.

So far I've found only ways to do the opposite which would be to [take images from the website and copy them to my webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/909686/1063093) which isn't what I want. I also know it would be easy to implement this using FTP but this option doesn't seem viable to me as it would be **way** too slow.

Let's say I have 50 pictures on my website, and want to view them all on the webapp as soon as it loads, getting them through FTP would be a huge bottleneck. I can live with the fact that I would need to use FTP to overwrite the image from the webapp to the website but I would like another solution if possible.

Is there an easy way to do this without FTP?

Comment: Why use a "web page" at all? For situations like this, plain sftp access is just perfect! Create an account for your clients and tell them to use some client able to use different network protocols. For example sftp or fish or webdavs. Many image viewers or file managers are able to. Good examples are `gwenview` and `dolphin`. That way you do not need any "web page" at all. Robust, available and well supported. Alternatively you could simply use `owncloud`. Offers all that you need and much more.

Comment: @arkascha Yes but my webapp offers **way** more than that. It's just another feature. So I really want it to be available.

Comment: Then add `webdavs` access to your "web app". (why is everything called an "app" these days?)

Comment: @arkascha I guess I could. But what if I want to code that from scratch.

Comment: Code a protocol from scratch? Sure, you can. But _why_? `webdav` implementations are available for all programming languages...

Comment: @arkascha Oh ok great I'll look into it then thanks.

Comment: Think of `webdav` as "http with write access" :-)

Comment: @arkascha Great. I'll give it a shot. Might want to formulate that as an answer tho.

Comment: No no, all fine. This is not an answer, but just a hint or suggestion. Not more. I just happen to think that it typically makes more sense to use existing and proven protocols instead of implementing everything again for each "web app".