# Intervention Image: Save image directly from an url with original file name and ext?

Tags: php, laravel, intervention, cakephp-3.1

How to get the filename, when taking image from a remote server? And how to save with original size and filename?

```
// Take remote image
$img = Image::make('http://image.info/demo.jpg');
// how to save in the img/original/demo.jpg
$img->save(????);
```

**I use Intervention,** (http://image.intervention.io/api/make) to build CakePHP 3 image Behavior, I want to provide an easy uploading from remote servers, and keep the original image as a source for future manipulation.

**EDIT**

**I ask,** is there the **Intervention Image** method that returns the name of the file, when taken from the remote server. I know php copy(), basename(), I can also use the CakePHP File  utilities, but it gives me the duplicate request on remote file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy Image from Remote Server Over HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909374/copy-image-from-remote-server-over-http)

Comment: No is not duplicate.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

response() does not return the original filename like Salines was requesting. This should work

```
$path = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/koFpQ.png';
$filename = basename($path);

Image::make($path)->save(public_path('images/' . $filename));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do it using the `make();` and `response();` methods. Check my code below.

Just keep in mind that `allow_url_fopen` must be enabled to fetch a remote image.

This will display my profile picture. If you are not using it with *Laravel Framework*, just replace return with `echo`.

```
$img = Image::make('https://i.stack.imgur.com/koFpQ.png');
header('Content-Type: image/png');
return $img->response();
```

Hope that helps and upvote my reply if useful ;)

If you need further help just ask.

Comment: I like it, no need to temporarily store on server. But I have a question. Is there a way to make it work for files in general? For example, my user can upload either a photo or a pdf document... how would I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

First Create new folder inside `public` folder called `images` , and execute the below code to download image from url and save it inside `public\images` folder

```
        $url = 'http://example.com/image.png';
        $img = public_path('images') . '\\test.png';
        file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```