# Read image from URL & upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not able to find a proper way to read an image from a URL and upload it using JavaScript/Ajax.

Suppose there is a URL: `https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1580483969/parisjs_transparent.png`.

I should be able to upload it now, but I guess to upload first I need to download it, so what will be the procedure?

Answer (score 8):

If the remote server allows CORS requests, it possible to download a remote image and read its contents. If the remote server does not allow CORS, the image can be shown (using a standard `<img src="..">` tag), but the content cannot be read - the [canvas gets tainted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image#What_is_a_tainted_canvas).

## Download image from remote URL using JavaScript when CORS is enabled

```js
function getImageFormUrl(url, callback) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
  img.onload = function (a) {
 var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
 canvas.width = this.width;
 canvas.height = this.height;
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

 var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
   
 // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
 var byteString;
 if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
  byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
 else
  byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

 // separate out the mime component
 var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

 // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
 var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
 for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
  ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
 }

 return callback(new Blob([ia], { type: mimeString }));
  }
  
  img.src = url;
}


getImageFormUrl('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b4/The_Sun_by_the_Atmospheric_Imaging_Assembly_of_NASA%27s_Solar_Dynamics_Observatory_-_20100819.jpg/628px-The_Sun_by_the_Atmospheric_Imaging_Assembly_of_NASA%27s_Solar_Dynamics_Observatory_-_20100819.jpg', function (blobImage) {
 var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('key1', 'value1');
 formData.append('key2', 'value2');
 formData.append('key2', 'value3');
 formData.append('imageToUpload', blobImage);
 
 console.log(blobImage);
 //use formData in "data" property in $.ajax
 //$.ajax({
  //blabla: blabla,
  //data: formData,
  //blabla: blabla
 //}})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let server download/upload your image. What you need to do is to create a text input field for image URL. Than via AJAX you send to backend the URL only and server gets its contents.

Comment: text input field or file input field? then I just need to send the image url to the server right?

Comment: Just a text input to paste the url. Than you send it to PHP and there you get the image content. Check [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909374/copy-image-from-remote-server-over-http).

Answer (score 0):

@DheerajAgrawal

see this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/WQXXT/3004/

you should customize that, where it says:

```
alert('start upload script here');
```